# How to sort a Varchar field which has data like ABC,ABC123,123 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a **section** column which is a **varchar** and I am trying to **sort** it in a way that i get the result as shown below,

```
Section  
-------
1  
100  
11  
180a  
18a  
18b  
19B  
2  
A1  
A10  
A11  
A18  
A180  
A189  
A19  
A1B  
AB1  
AB10  
AB100  
Aquaman  
B1  
B2  
B20  
B21  
B3  
B32  
S  
Superman
```

I am Expecting the Result to be as below. first i get the numbers sorted in ascending then the alpha numerical values then finally the char values.

It wont be an issue if it is first char values then alpha numerical then number.

```
Section
-------
1  
2  
11  
100  
18a  
18b  
19B  
180a  
A1  
A10  
A11  
A18  
A19  
A180  
A189  
A1B  
AB1  
AB10  
AB100  
B1  
B2  
B20  
B21  
B3  
B32  
Aquaman  
S  
Superman
```

i tried the below query, with which I got closer to an extent but not exactly to what i am expecting.

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section_suw
ORDER BY
case  when ISNUMERIC(Section)=0 then Section else '0' end,
case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=1 then CONVERT(INT, Section) else -1 end
```

Demo table for testing purpose,

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Section_suw
(
       Section varchar(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('AB1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B20')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('AB10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B3')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('AB100')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('B32')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('11')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A1B')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A180')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A189')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('180a')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('18a')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('18b')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A18')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('A19')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('19B')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('100')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('Superman')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('Aquaman')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section_suw (Section.Section) VALUES ('S')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to maintain a column which needs to behave both as text and as a number.  Instead, I suggest keeping the text and numeric portions in separate columns.  It's like Coke and Pepsi; you'll never have both cans in your hand at the same time.

Comment: Why does `S` appear after `Superman`?

Comment: You are @TimBiegeleisen i too thought the same when i saw this column,

It is a section of the address column and it seems this column has to have both number and char to it, sometimes only number and sometimes only char

in my case i am stuck with this column as i am working on a DB that is well built. :(

Comment: oops @GMB....i noticed it just now....i dont have the option to edit....or let me see if i can edit the question.

Comment: The only way I could see this feasibly working is to split your numerical and non numerical parts out, and then sort on those. *If* you have one a single numerical part that isn't *too* messy, however, if you have a have like `'1B9A'` it'll be messy.

Comment: @Larnu This would be a breeze on most other databases which support regex replacement.  But, not on SQL Server.

Comment: It's part of an address, and someone's address is "Superman"?

Comment: common @Larnu, i am not going to give you the exact column value. I have edited some

Comment: Does amaze me that SQL Server still lacks REGEX support, @TimBiegeleisen . Perhaps a CLR function would be the best bet, if the OP is going to have more complex values.

Comment: There is a clear bias here towards DC comic superheroes, but villains such as "Joker" are being left out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If we get something equivalent to the sample data I sent, it should be good. Actual data does have some values as messy as `1B9A` but that something we will have to live with till we update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This works as long as you're on a version of SQL Server that supports TRY_CAST (2012 onwards)

```
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section_suw
ORDER BY ISNULL(TRY_CAST(Section as int),2147483647),Section
```

[DBFiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=488c0f6d535ee0c92f8deaa5c446a2c1)

Comment: Wouldn't this, however, sort values like `'A180'` *before* `'A19'` and `'A2'`?

Comment: Your solution sorts `180a` _before_ `18a`.

Comment: ok so i tried this  

`SELECT Section FROM dbo.Section_suw
ORDER BY
case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=0  then  iif(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)>0,Section,'z'+Section) else '0' end,
case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=1 then CONVERT(INT, Section) else -1 end`  

result = i get all as expected except for the 180a before 18a

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Section FROM dbo.Section_suw
ORDER BY
case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=0  then  iif(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)>0,Section,'z'+Section) else '0' end
```

Comment: ok so i tried this      

`SELECT Section FROM dbo.Section_suw ORDER BY case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=0 then iif(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)>0,Section,'z'+Section) else '0' end, case when ISNUMERIC(Section)=1 then CONVERT(INT, Section) else -1 end`         

In result, i get all as expected, except for the `180a` before `18a`